# Stamping out and reentering a country with a native passport

Tags: visas, turkey

If I'm in Turkey on a US passport, but have a Turkish passport, do I need to leave the country to stamp out on the US passport and not overstay my visa?  Assuming I'm a citizen of both countries (and have always been a Turkish citizen with a Turkish passport).

Answer (score 4):

Türkiye allows it citizens, who are dual citizens, to enter on their other passport.

So that is not the problem.

Inside Türkiye you should be treated as a turkish citizen, but if you didn't state that when you applied for the eVisa they won't know that.

Showing you turkish passport when leaving should resolve any problems about the visa having expired.

---

> [Turkish nationality law - Dual citizenship - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkish_nationality_law#Dual_citizenship)
> Dual nationals **are not required** to use a Turkish passport to enter and leave Turkey; it is permitted to travel with a valid foreign passport (or national ID card for some nationals) and the Turkish National ID card.

Comment: Thank you for this information.  Just to make sure I understand: there should be no issue when exiting even if one hasn't stamped out the US passport, and even if one neglected to state when applying for the eVisa that one is a Turkish citizen?  For example as a US (non-Turkish) citizen I may be banned from the country for a certain amount of years for overstaying the visa.

Comment: @HorseHair You didn't require a visa in the first place, since you have a turkish passport (or ID). This situation/combination is not meantioned in any official source that I could find. [Entry into Turkey - Presidency of Migration Management](https://en.goc.gov.tr/entry-into-turkey)

Comment: Thank you again for your help

Comment: Sounds like they are trying to avoid military service?

Comment: I’m slightly confused @Mark Johnson If I’ve understood correctly, the entry stamp in the US passport won’t be matched by an exit stamp, nor (I assume, maybe wrongly) will the OP get an exit stamp in their Turkish passport. Could the ‘open’ stamp in the US passport cause a problem either next time the OP wants to visa Turkey using their US passport and/or if they ever need to apply for a visa to another destination using their US passport? Plus, I wonder if not disclosing their citizenship is legal when applying for an e-visa?

Comment: @JonCuster It's a question about a family member, not me. I've already done military service for the US, and am not obligated to for Turkey.  The family member entered on the US passport because their Turkish passport was not on them at the time.

Comment: @Traveller The official turkish site contained no information about this situation other than that they can enter with a non turkish passport. It is also not clear, based on their information, if a visa is required for the combination US Passport and turkish ID.

Comment: @HorseHair - so do/did they have a Turkish national ID? It is just, as asked, they seem to be trying hard to avoid letting Turkey authorities know that they are actually Turkish...

Comment: @JonCuster Yes they're a Turkish citizen. The stipulation listed above that they should declare they are a citizen when obtaining the visa was unknown, and the Turkish passport was not around at the time.